# Issues installing status.net

Tags: php, social-networking

How can I solve the Deprecated and Strict standards errors in PHP?
I got these errors while installing the status.net code:

> Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is
>   deprecated in /opt/lampp/lib/php/Mail.php on line 135
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method StatusNet::_sn_to_path() should
>   not be called statically in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/statusnet-0.9.6/lib/statusnet.php on line 266
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method PEAR::getStaticProperty() should
>   not be called statically in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/statusnet-0.9.6/lib/statusnet.php on line 277
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method StatusNet::loadConfigFile() should
>   not be called statically in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/statusnet-0.9.6/lib/statusnet.php on line 111
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of Memcached_DataObject::delete() should
>   be compatible with that of DB_DataObject::delete() in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/statusnet-0.9.6/classes/Memcached_DataObject.php
>   on line 23
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of Config::staticGet() should be
>   compatible with that of Memcached_DataObject::staticGet() in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/statusnet-0.9.6/classes/Config.php on line 31
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of Config::pkeyGet() should be
>   compatible with that of Memcached_DataObject::pkeyGet() in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/statusnet-0.9.6/classes/Config.php on line 31

Comment: What is the point of having strict standards when the answer everywhere is to turn off strict error reporting? You could read the errors and go through the statusnet code fixing the strict standards violations since the developer team didn't see a reason to do so when PHP came out with a new version.

Answer (score 1):

Insert the below line at the top of your site's index.php file.

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 0); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This are no "errors" that limit the functionality.
Change the `error_reporting` setting in your `php.ini` to not include E_DEPRECATED and E_STRICT errors. The php.ini has examples for that.